# Install KMDF programmatically using DiInstallDriver

Tags: c++, windows-7, kmdf, wdf

I want to install a kmdf driver on Windows 7 32bit machine. At first I used hdwwiz (the add hardware tool) and it worked correctly.

Now I want to install it programmatically using a software. After some research I found `DiInstallDriver` I used the following code

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring FilePath = L"<file name>.inf";
    bool result = DiInstallDriver(NULL, FilePath.c_str(), DIIRFLAG_FORCE_INF, false);
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    if (!result){
        printf("The driver is not installed \r\n");
        printf("The error is %x ", error);
    }else
    {
        printf("The driver is installed correctly !");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

After running the software I get "The driver is installed correctly !", that means the functions returns with success but I cannot find it in the Device Manager?

Any idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: `DiInstallDriver` preinstalls the driver into the driver store. It doesn't add a device into the device tree. You'd need to actually plug in a matching device to your system.

Comment: @KubaOber, thanks for your reply. My driver doesn't need any device! What other function do you suggest I use that replicate the use of hdwwiz ?

Comment: Look at the [devcon](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/setup/devcon) sources.

Comment: @KubaOber, when I use
devcon dp_add <file path>.inf

"Adding the specified driver package to the machine failed.
devcon failed."

Any idea ?

Comment: You've got the source code. Build it, debug it and see why it fails.

Comment: @KubaOber, thanks I'll give it a try.